# What is the most reliable and fastest type or data structure to store data using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsset

I am looking for the type or data structure to store a big number of same type primitives on my app (Mac OS X or iOS) using Objective C. As I understood NSNumber stores only one primitive (correct me if I am wrong). I have, let's say, thousands of integers or strings. **Which would be the best solution to put, store and access them there?** NSSet, NSArray, NSMutableArray, NSDictionary, NSMutableDictionary or something else? I know that they have different features, but I care basically only about the performance of basic operations (putting, storing, retrieving).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It only depends on how you want to ADD, STORE and REMOVE this data.

First Let us go through each type of Data Structure that is available to us in Objective-C:

**Primitive Array**

This is the most basic type of storage in Objective-C(or C) which is used to store primitives. 
Ex: `int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};`
The limitation to this is

- Can only store primitive types.
- Array size cannot be changed once declared.
- Can only be retrieved by its index.
- Can store only single type of data, defined at the time of declaring the array.

**NSArray**

This is a container for storing objects. Any object which is of type `NSObject` (or inherits from `NSObject`) or is of type 'id' can be stored in `NSArray`.

- Once initialized, it cannot be mutated i.e. array size cannot be changed nor the objects it contains can be modified. This is good in terms of security.
- Objects can only be accessed by its index.

**NSMutableArray**

Same as `NSArray`, but

- Can be mutated, i.e. the existing objects can be modified and also new objects can be added or deleted.

**NSSet**

Same as `NSArray` but

- Stores only unique objects.
- Objects cannot be accessed by its index. Objects can only be accessed by enumeration.

**NSMutableSet**

Same as `NSSet`, but

- Can be mutated, i.e. objects can be added or removed at a later point of time.

**NSOrderedSet**

Same as `NSArray`, i.e. objects are stored and retrieved by an index, but

- Stores only unique objects.

**NSMutableOrderedSet**

Same as `NSMutableArray`, but

- Stores only unique objects.

**NSDictionary**

Can store any type of data.

- Objects are stored and retrieved by a key.
- Once initialized, cannot be mutated i.e. cannot add new key-values nor can update existing objects associated to a particular key.

**NSMutableDictionary**

Same as `NSDictionary`

- Can be mutated, i.e. new objects can be added or removed and existing objects can be modified.

This was a short description about mostly used Data Structures in Objective-C. These are used based on the need of the program and how data is to be manipulated.

Therefore,

- If you want to store thousands of numbers and strings and want access it by its index value then use `NSMutableArray`. If you are not going to add, remove or modify any objects in the future then use `NSArray`.
- If you want to store data but do not want duplicates and want to access it by its index the use `NSOrderedSet`/`NSMutableOrderedSet`
- If you want to store data but do not want duplicates and its order also doesn't matter then use `NSSet`/`NSMutableSet`.
- If you want to access data by a particular **key** then use `NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary`

**Regarding Performance**

- Since `NSSet` doesn't contain any order, they are more performant than `NSArray`
- **[Here](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/collections.html) is a very good and detailed article on performance characteristics for each Data Structure discussed above**

  ```
  Class                      Time [ms]    1,000,000 elements
  ```

  Adding

  ```
  NSMutableOrderedSet         3190.52
  NSMutableDictionary         2522.47
  NSMutableSet                2511.96
  NSMutableArray              1423.26
  NSSet                          8.03
  ```

  Random Access

  ```
  NSMutableOrderedSet           10.74
  NSMutableDictionary            9.18
  NSMutableArray                 8.08
  NSMutableSet                   4.47
  NSSet                          3.56
  ```

To know more about Objective-C Data Types and Data Structure, read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html)

Comment: Since it is very brilliant description of the different types with different features (good explanation/reminder for every user), still the question is open about real-time performance. For example, a good comparison, but only between NSData and NSArray: http://iwantmyreal.name/blog/2012/09/29/a-faster-array-in-objective-c/

Comment: Thanks @DariusMiliauskas, that was appreciated! I have added an article on performance characteristics for each Data Structure described above. Kindly have a look at it.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Thanks for sharing.